# Ruby on rails tutorial chapter 10...account activation not matching route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Trying to go through the ruby on rails tutorial on chapter 10. Have a pretty decent understanding of routing so far.  Here is the issue: basically with account activations you send a token to an email which it then performs a hash on and tries to verify everything (after the link is clicked).  I have a route set up for `/account_activations/:id/edit`

and this is the url I am sending:
 `account_activations/$2a$10$GTxhcOsTRWNvmDMwaWLJk.WM1xgnICwXUpkymIN5oRqvWRIb%2FtnXy/edit?email=me%40gmail.com`

I have verified that the hash is correct in several different testing scenarios. It then tells me it cannot find a route for it.  Quoting the closest thing (in terms of priority) as:

```
edit_account_activation_path    GET /account_activations/:id/edit(.:format) account_activations#edit
```

The path in routes.rb looks like: 
  `resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]`

Looks to me like those should match though as :id should just act as a wildcard for the string. If anyone needs more info let me know.  Would really like to understand why this isn't working.  Thanks.

Comment: You want send email as params for edit?

Comment: yeah, but if I understand correctly, anything after the ? is packaged as key/value pairs and can be accessed in params anyways via params[:email] right? Like its basically ambiguous and doesn't need to be stated in the routing.

Comment: same problem here, Could you solve it? I also have another strange bug, the edit_account_activations_path(...) produces <base url>/account_activations/edit.PDqYpYHPaaj62FTmPx0isg?email=foo%40bar.com as you can see the edit action is not perfomed here, don't know how to solve it